# sudden Qt error when using matplotlib on cmd

Tags: python, windows, qt, matplotlib

There are questions referring to this same error message, but the crucial difference is that **I am not (deliberately) using Qt. I don't actually know what it is, and I am trying to run my program on cmd, not through any IDE.** I have been using matplotlib without any problems until just now, when i suddenly got the error message:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"
in "".
Available platform plugins are: direct2d, minimal, offscreen, windows.
Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
```

here is a sample program which produces this error, although I suspect it is a consequence of the package being used, not the program

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nums = [1,2,3,4]
labels = ["one","two","three","four"]
colours, one, two = plt.pie(nums, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%')
plt.legend(colours, labels, loc="best")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

again, I installed matplotlib years ago, and have been using it just fine until now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit: python version 3.7.1, matplotlib version 3.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just fixed it by upgrading matplotlib to version 3.2.1
not sure why that worked but hey